# Enabled VPN -- Site to site -- Cannot access internet now .. Cisco ASA 5505

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-commands, nat

I had just enabled site to site VPN access  ...   I am assuming something got messed up with NAT  ...  It's the strangest thing ..   I cannot find anything wrong through ASDM, or CLI .. Yet, I can ping out of the network, and pings are received by host, replied to, and then blocked by the ASA.  I can get out, but no return traffic ..  Here is my config:

```
    Result of the command: "show run"

names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.10.100 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 74.xx.xx.225 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
object-group network PPTP-server
object-group network hst-10.1.10.122
 description VPN-Server
access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any interface outside eq pptp 
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0
static (inside,outside) tcp interface pptp 10.1.10.122 pptp netmask 255.255.255.255 
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 74.xx.xx.230 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto isakmp enable inside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.1.10.104-10.1.10.254 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect pptp 
!
```

This is slightly irritating, however I am assuming that it's something pretty simple..  Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've added an ACL to the outside interface that doesn't permit ICMP ("ping"), and the default inspection policy doesn't track icmp (no inspect icmp)

(And you've not setup "site to site vpn". You added an internal PPTP server. Those `crypto isakmp policy`'s are only cluttering the config -- if that's actually all of your config.)

Comment: That's exactly what it was ..  I permitted ICMP and all is well ...  Also, I did set up site-to site .. It just contained sensitive info that I didn't want to take the time to "filter, so I just removed that section.  The PPTP is our client to server VPN.  Good catch on the ICMP!